# Preview inside events on popover

Tags: fullcalendar

Can we navigate through events inside this one when we click +x more when the popover is open or can we preview over there?

[image]

This is regarding fullcalendar features where we need the functionality to view the content of popover events below is the link where you can see the demo.

[navigate to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7tgP.png)
In this image when we click on more button a new popover is display

[navigate to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PDgZ.png)
Here we can see the popover where list of events are render, So my question is can we navigate to these events or can we preview the details of this event.

Link for fullcalendar demo : https://fullcalendar.io/demos

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "navigate through events" exactly? And what do you mean by "preview over there"? Preview what? Over where? Please see [ask] and then clarify your question with more detail, and preferably show some code you tried in order to implement your requirement and explain the exact problem/error you're facing. Remember that we cannot see your screen or read your mind. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my query if you understand my query it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but it's a still a bit unclear. What _exactly_ do you mean by "navigate to these events"? What do you expect to happen, and when, and how does it relate to the popover? What are you trying to do which you are unable to do, precisely? Obviously you can see the events by clicking on the "+5more" button. And what do you mean by "preview details" exactly? You still haven't defined precisely what it is you need.

Comment: If you want to display extra details about a fullCalendar event you can use the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) to alter the HTML of the event, and/or run some code to attach some external popover or similar thing to it. That is no different whether the event is inside fullCalendar's popover or not. I still don't know what actual problem you're experiencing or what code you want help with.